# Could you guys help me ping [2607:fcd0:fa80:2a10:fc7e:b081:f933:7a0a]

Tags: networking, putty, ping, ipv6

I bought a VPS, they give me the IPv6 address ahead, and I can not rich it (no matter cmd/Putty/Filezilla). When I opened a ticket, they tell me it just works fine (they pinged it and works).

What id I do: LAMP and vsftpd all installed, ufw 20-25, 80, 443 open.
(already changed IP once).
Use VPN linked to different locations to ping the IP.

```
ping [2607:fcd0:fa80:2a10:fc7e:b081:f933:7a0a]
```

The result shows 100% loss

So I need you guys to help me check it's my problem or their's.

Comment: Is whatever network your computer is on IPv6 capable? Does it route IPV6? Does your ISP supply a publicly routable IPV6 network? Just having a (link local) IPV6 address on your computer is not enough.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ ping 2607:fcd0:fa80:2a10:fc7e:b081:f933:7a0a
PING 2607:fcd0:fa80:2a10:fc7e:b081:f933:7a0a(2607:fcd0:fa80:2a10:fc7e:b081:f933:7a0a) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 2607:fcd0:fa80:2a10:fc7e:b081:f933:7a0a: icmp_seq=1 ttl=52 time=144 ms
64 bytes from 2607:fcd0:fa80:2a10:fc7e:b081:f933:7a0a: icmp_seq=2 ttl=52 time=143 ms
64 bytes from 2607:fcd0:fa80:2a10:fc7e:b081:f933:7a0a: icmp_seq=3 ttl=52 time=143 ms
```

It's your problem.